# 三項演算子で配列操作するときに何も代入したくない

Tags: javascript

## 該当原始コード

```
function test(a, b, c){
 a[b] = c % 2 === 0 ? "グースー" : here!!!!!
}
```

上のようなコードの場合、「:」の後には必ず何かしら代入するものを書かなければなりませんが、何も代入したくありません。
nullやundefinedではそれが代入されますし、もう素直にifを使うべきですか？

Comment: 条件が True の時だけ何かしたいのであれば if 文の方が適切なように感じます。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

条件演算子を利用する上で省略可能なオペランドは無いです([参考](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator))。

実行前後で値が変わってほしくない、ということであれば、自身を代入すれば良いかと思います。

```js
function test(a, b, c) {
  a[b] = c % 2 === 0 ? "グースー" : a[b];
}

const a = ["キスー", "キスー"];

test(a, 0, 0);
test(a, 1, 1);

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

[論理積](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND)を使うのはいかがでしょうか。

```js
function test(a, b, c) {
  c % 2 === 0 && (a[b] = "グースー");
}

const a = ["キスー", "キスー"];

test(a, 0, 0);
test(a, 1, 1);

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

三項演算子で条件が真のときだけ何かをすると言うのは無理そうなのでif文を使うことにします